# How can I make KeyboardEvents change value of HTMLInputElement?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create unit tests for code that transforms the value of an input element as characters are typed into it. It's a simple keyup event handler, and it works as expected when I type characters at the keyboard.

When I try to create an automated test where keydown and keyup events are dispatched, I can see the event handler firing, but the value property of the input element never changes.  I've tried using JQuery to fire events, and using the basic DOM methods; neither seems to work.

Can anyone suggest how to make the value change? I assume it's possible, as Selenium tests do it.

This is a sample of the code:

```
    function setupTest(elem) {
      const input = elem[0] as HTMLInputElement;
      const letters = "aSdFgH";
      let index = 0;

      $("#injectButton").click(() => {
        const char = letters.charAt(index);
        const keydown = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
            key: char,
            shiftKey: char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z'
        });

        const keyup = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {
            key: char,
            shiftKey: char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z'
        });
        index++;
        input.dispatchEvent(keydown);
        input.dispatchEvent(keyup);
    });

    const report = (name, event) => {
        const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
        console.log(name, target.value, event);
    }

    $(elem)
        .focus(event => report("FOCUS", event))
        .keydown(event => report("KEYDOWN", event))
        .keyup(event => report("KEYUP", event))
        .blur(event => report("BLUR", event))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Is this real syntax: `const input = elem[0] as HTMLInputElement;`?

Comment: @zer00ne - Looks like TypeScript

Comment: I think it will not work due to security reasons.
Read the note below: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Example

Comment: @zer00ne sorry,it's TypeScript. I thought I'd reduced it all to JS, but I missed a bit. The cast doesn't affect functionality.

Comment: @ArtemBozhko maybe you're right, but the console messages show that the events are firing. I can't see anything in the MDN page that suggests the default action of the event won't happen.

Comment: @Chris Note: Manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

@Artem Bozhko is right - this isn't possible. Synthetic events (those created in script) have *isTrusted* false. Untrusted events cannot trigger default actions, so they never modify the input value. For obvious security reasons, *isTrusted* is a read-only property, so as far as I can tell, that's it.

This unfortunately makes it impossible to create unit tests that verify UI behaviour in the browser.  I assume Selenium gets round this by lower-level interaction with the browser, but Selenium is a bit heavyweight for the kind of unit tests I'm aiming for.